# Angular 8 @angular/core/core"' has no exported memberafter installing angular-datatables

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-datatables

I have installed angular-datatables after adding reference into my component. I run the ngServe and got an error message:

**`ERROR in node_modules/angular-datatables/src/angular-datatables.directive.d.ts(39,21)node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'. has no exported member 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration'. has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.`**

I have searched it everywhere but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: install the same version of datatables as you have Angular. so if you have 8  version of angular, then downgrade datatables to 8 also. Or as an option you can upgrade the angular